# typo3 connect my controller and action with my front

Tags: typo3

I have created a plugin in my extension. I installed from site package boots... and I want to add some action to edit and list etc.
I can have what I have register but my problem is the controller didn't connect with my front.
Let's forget about the record and plugin I have created and let's say I have TestController with helloWorldAction to display some string or whatever and I have done the configplugin in the localconf.php and I checked mille time the vendor and keyextension and the controller name.   I have created the html so it will return that but still didn't work. I have even tried

```php
var_dump($motivation);
die('listAction called!');
```

to see the connection between my controller action and the front.
nothing. like it didn't exist.
I have tried the

```
tt_content.list.20.imbus_motivation = FLUIDTEMPLATE
tt_content.list.20.imbus_motivation {
    file = EXT:imbus/Resources/Private/Templates/ImbusMotivation/List.html

    dataProcessing {
        10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
        10 {
            table = tx_imbus_domain_model_motivation
            pidInList = {$plugin.tx_imbus_domain_model_motivation.persistence.storagePid}
            where = 1=1
            orderBy = uid
            as = motivations
            dataProcessing {
                10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\FilesProcessor
                10 {
                    references.fieldName = image
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I can see the data from the plugin I created but I want to add and edit and delete. So when I have begin using the controller it didn't work and I can't have the list from there.
Please help me with detailed information to connect my controller to the front with a simple example which is working for you.
I'm using TYPO3 v11.5.32 and PHP 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two different approaches:

- Content elements with DataProcessors
- Plugins

### Content elements

These are suitable in case data is managed by editors in the TYPO3 backend and displayed in the frontend. A visitor usually cannot do much with data here. A common example is a slider configured by editors.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/AddingYourOwnContentElements.html

### Plugins

These should be preferred if a lot of data management happens in the TYPO3 frontend, e.g. filtering, editing, deleting, ...

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/Extbase/Reference/FrontendPlugins.html

Comment: no let's forget about the two approach, i need only to see the connection betwin my controller action with front , forgot the plugin , i need a simple return as string or aything, my problem is to do the connection with my controller action it didn't work at all for me, this is my problem now i need the steps of a simple exemple to see from where the problem ccome from it isn't the plugin or anything

Comment: Ehm, when you post TS with a Dataprocessor, but are asking how to connect controller action, you *have* a problem with the two approaches. You are trying the one, but need the other. But if you still want to solve it in such a contradictory way - good luck.